# How could I multiply list in the elixir?

Tags: elixir

I have a list

```
[1, 4, 3]
```

I want to multiply it, something like:

```
[1, 4, 3] * 3 # => [1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please upvote the answer by Dogbert, that is a) faster and b) brings way more value than my silly link to the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe, the Elixir idiomatic solution would be to use [`List.duplicate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#duplicate/2)

```
list |> List.duplicate(3) |> List.flatten
```

---

Please note, that if `list` is expected to have nested lists, and they are not to be flattened, one should use:

```
list |> List.duplicate(3) |> :lists.concat
```

— credits go to @Dogbert

Comment: If you just replace `List.flatten` with `:lists.concat`, you get the fastest solution in this thread (benchmark in my answer). +1 for `List.duplicate/2`.

Comment: @Dogbert Frankly, it’s “fastest” within a standard deviation interval :) I would leave this answer intact for the sake of wording “idiomatic.” In “our” answer I would go with `:lists.concat(:lists.duplicate(@list, 100))` to keep it, say, single syntax styled.

Comment: Yes, the speed is pretty much identical with my best but `List.duplicate` is certainly more idiomatic than `Enum.map` here.

Comment: There is one potential problem with this approach though. If `list` contains any lists inside, they'll all get flattened as well: `[1, [2], 3] |> List.duplicate(2) |> List.flatten # => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. With `:lists.concat`: `[1, [2], 3] |> List.duplicate(2) |> :lists.concat #=> [1, [2], 3, 1, [2], 3]`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `Enum.map` with `:lists.concat` (`Enum.concat` is much slower than `:lists.concat`):

```
:lists.concat(Enum.map(1..100, fn(_) -> @list end))
```

Here are some benchmarks for the suggestions in this thread and some of my other attempts:

```
defmodule BasicBench do
  use Benchfella

  @list Enum.to_list(1..100)

  bench "1 by @asiniy" do
    Enum.reduce(1..100, [], fn(_, acc) -> acc ++ @list end)
  end

  bench "2 by @radubogdan" do
    Enum.take(Stream.cycle(@list), 10000)
  end

  bench "3 by @Dogbert" do
    Enum.flat_map(1..100, fn(_) -> @list end)
  end

  bench "4 by @Dogbert" do
    Enum.concat(Enum.map(1..100, fn(_) -> @list end))
  end

  bench "5 by @Dogbert" do
    :lists.concat(Enum.map(1..100, fn(_) -> @list end))
  end

  bench "6 by @mudasobwa" do
    @list |> List.duplicate(100) |> List.flatten
  end

  bench "7 by @mudasobwa + @Dogbert" do
    :lists.concat(List.duplicate(@list, 100))
  end
end
```

Output:

```
benchmark name              iterations   average time
7 by @mudasobwa + @Dogbert       50000   35.72 µs/op
5 by @Dogbert                    50000   38.92 µs/op
6 by @mudasobwa                  10000   124.30 µs/op
3 by @Dogbert                    10000   174.63 µs/op
4 by @Dogbert                    10000   242.24 µs/op
2 by @radubogdan                  2000   924.04 µs/op
1 by @asiniy                      1000   2143.24 µs/op
```

Comment: Feel free to suggest more ways and I'll add it to the benchmarks.

Comment: `@list |> List.duplicate(100) |> List.flatten`

Comment: @mudasobwa added!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `Stream.cycle/1`

```
iex> stream = Stream.cycle([1, 4, 3])
iex> Enum.take(stream, 9)
[1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3]
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it.

Comment: @asiniy in this contrived example there is nothing wrong; but this solution is lazy and easily parallelized out of the box.

Comment: But if you do want a list at the end, this is slow. If you just want to iterate, this should be fast.

Comment: Agree with Dogbert, the fastest is using erlang :lists module, for the sake of the question I think this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing which comes to mind is:

```
def multiply_list(list, factor) do
  Enum.reduce(1..factor, [], fn(_, acc) -> acc ++ list end)
end
```

Comment: What about my answer?